# Heroku R14 For Few Minutes After Deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Heroku app runs with no errors, but gets a R14 (memory quota exceeded) for a couple minutes after pushing changes. This happens regardless of restarting my dynos and always resolves itself after about two minutes. Also, it seems to be responding fine to API requests. I think it's stalling on template rendering.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Yeah looking at the logs it seems that it's mainly just timing out while trying to render the view (maybe unrelated to the R14 I was seeing earlier). Regardless, this only happens right after deploy. Normally the views render very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like New Relic might be really helpful here. It will tell you what object, methods, SQL calls etc are stacking up memory. If you can't diagnose it locally I would give that a try.

Comment: Yeah using New Relic it shows all the time being spent trying to render the layout. It also seems to happen particularly when I push new assets. I am precompiling them locally before pushing though so not sure why this would be an issue.

Comment: ok, you are aware that the first request after redeploying on heroku takes longer than subsequent requests right? How many dynos are you running?

Comment: I'm only using one dyno right now so I'm sure that's part of the issue. However the app is serving API requests during this period so it seems odd that it's just hanging on the rendering. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I can't say for sure without looking it up but I do know that if you run only one dyno they go into a sort of sleep mode when not accessed for 1-2 minutes, then take forever on the first request that wakes them up. running more than 1 dyno prevents them from sleeping. not sure if that is helpful. have you seen this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling

Comment: I'm paying for the slightly better service (Hobby) that uses one dyno but doesn't sleep. Are deploys performed differently when using multiple dynos though?

Comment: Oh I think I may have solved it. When compiling the assets locally I did not explicitly specify a couple files that were not included in application.js/css. So it must have been compiling on first request. Sorry for the trouble!